How to keep my Powershell script running without problems headlessly?
What is the problem?

I wanted to keep it running all the time background, but I cannot execute my powershell script headlessly.

Detailed explanation
the script
let's start by showing my script first.
$logPath = "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Powershell\logfile.txt"
Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "Script started at $(Get-Date)"


# Define the files to watch and their respective destinations
$filesToWatch = @(
    @{ Source = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\pp.dpl"; Destination = "Z:\watch\" },
    @{ Source = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ll.dpl"; Destination = "Y:\watch\" },
    @{ Source = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ee.dpl"; Destination = "X:\watch\" }
)

# Create a watcher for each file
foreach ($file in $filesToWatch) {
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($file.Source)
    $watcher.Filter = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($file.Source)
    $watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite

    # Define the action to take when the file is modified
    $action = {
        try {
            $sourceFile = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $destinationDir = $Event.MessageData.Destination
            Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationDir -Force
            Write-Host "File $sourceFile copied to $destinationDir at $(Get-Date)" 
        } catch {
            $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            Add-Content -path $logPath -Value "Error: $errorMessage at $(Get-Date)"
        }
    }

    # Register the event for file changes
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher -EventName Changed -Action $action -MessageData $file

    # Start the FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
}

# Keep the script running
Write-Host "Monitoring files for changes. Press Ctrl+C to exit."
Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "Monitoring started at $(Get-Date)"

while ($true) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}


As you can see, it doesn't really do anything important, it's just a simple script that copies a few files on my main machine to different samba network drives whenever they are modified.
I should mention you, if you just right-click on this and hit run in powershell, it will always have a powershell window on the startup bar, but it's anyway running very well, so please don't say your script is wrong, I've run it manually once every time I've tested it.
first try

so I firstly registered it with the task scheduler.

I added powershell.exe with the following arguments: -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File “C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Powershell\script.ps1”.
At first, I didn't have the log part in the script, and it threw 0xC100013A error.
I wondered what was wrong, so I added the log part, The log file shows that it ran successfully, but the task scheduler started spitting out 0x40010004 errors and the file was not copied.
I tried changing the scheduler's setting to stop the existing instance, but it didn't work.
NSSM
Finally, I installed NSSM and made it a service, but it still doesn't work, even though it's running fine when I look at the service window...
Using UNC
thanks to reply this thread, @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style
I changed the filesToWatch part like this
$filesToWatch = @(
    @{ Source = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\pp.dpl"; Destination = "\\192.168.0.299\NAS storage first\watch" },
    @{ Source = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ll.dpl"; Destination = "\\192.168.0.299\NAS storage second\watch\" },
    @{ Source = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\ee.dpl"; Destination = "\\192.168.0.299\NAS storage third\watch\" }

of course it worked while I ran on powershell headly, but it doesn't copy anything (or doesn't watch) via headless run

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Remove Samba Windows mounted drive letters for destinations and replace those with the UNC path of the server shares you mount those drive letters to. I'd start with that for troubleshooting.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I edited this post, also wrote a sad result, thanks

The security context of the run/execution will need access to the UNC path share. If you are running as system and it is domain joined, you can add <computername>$ AD computer object to have the access for the operations it needs to complete. Or else you could try to map a network drive as that execution context with explicit credential when it runs to get the drive mounted with that security for the context it executes perhaps. I see a few ways to test this but I'm unfamiliar with your environment specifics. Domain joined server and workstation/server on both sides?

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I don't know understand your question very well.... just explain myself. In my case I use a router and connect two pc. LAN1 is main pc(the script would running), and LAN2 is ubuntu server installed mini pc(destination hard drives). I made samba protocol to possible to connect with 777 permission. if it's from local network, no need to login

If you just want to mirror the changed files, why not just use robocopy?  Run it as a scheduled task.

@GregW I..i really never heard robocopy before... but actually it looks too great for me, thanks very much!!

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do say I'm fine, but I'll write the solution I found, and I'm sure others will chime in if there's a better way.
Solution
Write a simple vbscript, and create a shortcut to it in the startup folder inside appdata\roaming.
The vbscript looks like this
Set objShell = CreateObject(“WScript.Shell”)
objShell.Run “powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Powershell\script.ps1""", 0, False

This shouldn't cause any problems because the script will run headlessly after the user logs on, at the very end of the authorization.
How I got here
@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle 's comment inspired me a lot, and made me realize that the problem is the permissions blah blah blah.
It made me realize that my user account is already conflated with my simple NAS, which is configured as a ubuntu server, but service created with nssm or scheduled task are independent of my user permissions, i.e. they run after boot and before login via windows hello.
Now I have two options: either I can make the NAS individually accessible with a user password or something so that the script can work within its permissions,
or I can just let it run with full privileges.
as you can see, I choose second way.
